# Gaussian integral with a pole of order 2

Tags: complex-analysis, gaussian-integral

I need to evaluate the following integral (this arises from starting with a gaussian variable x and asking what is the average of $(1-x)^{-1}$):
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1-x)^2}
\end{equation}
Is there any meaningful way to make this integral finite and well defined?

Comment: your integral doesn't exist (even in a priciple value sense) because as $x\rightarrow 1$ the integrand behaves as $1/(e (x-1)^2)$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. is this valid for any higher power, namely $e^{-x^2}(1-x)^{-n}$ for $n=3,4,5 \dots$?